# $x^2+y^3 = z^4$ for positive integers

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

How can I solve this diophatine equation :

$$x^2+y^3=z^4$$
for $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$

I tried to look on wolfram alpha yet it seems like there aren't any solutions...

Comment: Do you have any reason to think there is a solution?  Cubes and fourth powers are rare.

Comment: According to me there aren't any solutions, yet how to prove such a result ?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg yes in $\mathbb{N}^3$ but not in : $\mathbb{Z}^3_{>0}$

Comment: @Dando18 but not in $\mathbb{Z}^3_{>0}$

Comment: One solution is $(x,y,z)=(28,8,6)$.

Comment: @lulu Ok nice one !

Comment: I did it this way:  write $y^3=(z^2-x)(z^2+x)$.  Sacrificing generality, search for cases where both $z^2\pm x$ are cubes.  Then we want $z^2=\frac {a^3+b^3}2$.  I found the first example of that.

Comment: A second solution is $(x,y,z)=(1792,128,48)$, I expect (but have not shown) that there are infinitely many.  I have no idea about the generalization.

Comment: Ok nice one ! I am going to try to make a $C++$ program in order to find "a logic" in the solutions...

Comment: Ok, I knopw how to prove there are infinitely many solutions ! We know thank's to you that : $(28,8,6)$ is a solution. And that : $lcm(2,3,4) = 12$ Hence, if $(x,y,z)$ is a solution then : $(2^6x, 2^4y, 2^3z)$ is a solution

Comment: set $z^2 -x = y$, then get $(2y+1)^2 - 8z^2 = 1$, which will have inf solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$X^{n}+Y^{n+1}=Z^{n+2}$$

Solution always can be written, for example.

$$X=(c^2-b^2)^{(n+2)}b^{(n^2+2n-1)}c^{(n+1)^2}$$

$$Y=(c^2-b^2)^{(n+1)}b^{(n-1)(n+2)}c^{n(n+1)}$$

$$Z=(c^2-b^2)^{n}b^{(n-1)(n+1)}c^{(n^2+1)}$$

If you make this change.  $X^2+Y^3=Z^4$

$$p=tz(2zk^2+t)$$

$$s=tzk^2(2zk^2-t)$$

The result of such decision.

$$X=sp^3$$

$$Y=2tzk^2p^2$$

$$Z=kp^2$$

Where the number $t,z,k$ - integers and set us.  You may need after you get the numbers, divided by the common divisor.

Comment: I know I am seeing this after a very long time.. but I had to ask. could you give me some source where I can read the derivation of the solution of x^n + y&(n+1) = z^(n+2)?  It seems really interesting.

Answer (score 4):

This is a special case of the *generalized Fermat equation* 
$$x^p+y^q=z^r$$
For $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r}\le 1$ it has only finitely many coprime integer solutions, as has been proved by Darmon and Granville. For $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r}>1$ however, there are infinitely many coprime nonzero integer solutions, given by a finite set of 2-parameter families, see Beukers, The Diophantine equation $Ax^p + By^q = Cz^r$, Duke Math. J. 91 (1998), 61-88. The explicit parameterizations (with proofs) can be found in Chapter 14 of Cohen's book
Number Theory, Vol. II.

Comment: Theorem 2 here http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Research/12.Granville/pub12.pdf

Comment: If $C$ is a constant $\in \mathbb{N}$, can we say that : $C+x^p+y^q = z^r$ has infinitely man solutions ?

Comment: but $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} > 1$ ...

Comment: @Mudream Yes, you are right. Then we have infinitely many coprime solutions.