# Solutions to $i^5+j^6=k^7$ where $(i,j,k)\in\mathbb{Z^+}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was faced with this problem-

> Find all possible $(i,j,k)$ if $i^5+j^6=k^7$ where $(i,j,k)\in\mathbb{Z^+}$.

Does this have any solutions at all.If $\mathbb{Z^+}$ was changed to $\mathbb{Z}$ do I have any solutions?

Although the exponents are different can Fermats Last Theorem be extended to help in this problem.

Thanks for any help on how to approach this kind of problem!!

Note:Trivial solutions like $(0,0,0);(0,1,1);(1,0,1)$ may be excluded.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2312079/x2y3-z4-for-positive-integers/2312120#2312120

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Infinite solutions in $\mathbb{Z^+}$ can be obtained by letting $i=2^{6x}$, $j=2^{5x}$, and $k=2^{y}$. Then 
$$i^5+j^6=2^{30x}+2^{30x}=2^{30x+1}=k^7={2^{7y}}\Leftrightarrow 7y-30x=1$$
which has infinite  positive integer solutions because $\gcd(7,30)=1$: $x=7n+3$, $y=30n+13$ where $n$ is a non-negative integer.

However, there are more solutions: if $(i,j,k)$ is a solution then $(m^{6\cdot 7} i,m^{5\cdot 7}j ,m^{5\cdot 6} k)$ is another solution.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathbb Z+ $ changed to $\mathbb Z$ , then putting $i=0,j=0,k=0$ one by one you will get $(i,j,k)=(0,s^7,s^6),(s^7,0,s^5),(s^6,-s^5,0)$ where $s\in\mathbb N$ & $s=0$

In $\mathbb Z+$ , I am still searching the solutions.

EDIT:

As Robert Z explained ,you have also infinite solutions in $\mathbb Z+$

And you can see this too [similar to your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2326050/proof-that-x3y4-z31-has-infinitely-many-solutions)